# threads safe linked list fine grained in C

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list

I'm implementing a linked list with fine grained locking, meaning a lock in every node.

When I'm adding a new node, I want to pass only 2 arguments: key and value.
How can I make sure each node has a different lock? The lock is implemented by `pthread_mutex_t`.

This is my implementation to add:

```
int setos_add(int key, void* value)
{
volatile setos_node* node = head;
volatile setos_node* prev;

pthread_mutex_t new_mutex;  //wrong: it will put the same lock to everyone

//lock the head node
if(pthread_mutex_lock(&(node->mutex)) == 0){
    printf("failed locking\n");
    exit(1);
}

// go through nodes until the key of "node" exceeds "key"
// new node should then be between "prev" and "node"
while ((node != NULL) && (node->key < key)) {
    prev = node;  //already locked
    node = node->next;
    //locking 2 nodes each time
    if (node != NULL){
        if(pthread_mutex_lock(&(node->mutex)) == 0){
            printf("failed locking\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (node -> key < key){  //else: we need also preve staying locked for       the insertions
        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&(prev->mutex)) != 0){
            printf("failed unlocking\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

// if node is same as our key - key already in list
if ((node != NULL) && (node->key == key)){

    if (node != NULL){  //not the end of the list
        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&(node->mutex)) != 0){
            printf("failed unlocking\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (prev != NULL){ //not the begining of the list
        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&(prev->mutex)) != 0){
            printf("failed unlocking\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// allocate new node and initialize it
setos_node* new_node = (setos_node*) malloc(sizeof(setos_node));
new_node->key = key;
new_node->value = value;
new_node->mutex = new_mutex;  //to change
if(pthread_mutex_init(&(new_node-> mutex), NULL) != 0){
    printf("failed init mutex");
    exit(1);
}


// place node into list
new_node->next = node;
prev->next = new_node;

if (node != NULL){ //not the end of the list
    if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&(node->mutex)) != 0){
        printf("failed unlocking\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

if (prev != NULL){ //not the begining of the list
    if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&(prev->mutex)) != 0){
        printf("failed unlocking\n");
        exit(1);

    }
}

return 1;
}
```

You can see that in the third line I'm defining the `pthread_mutex_t` to the node. But doing so, will each new node have the same `pthread_mutex_t`?

How can I do it right?

Comment: You really want one lock per node? Huh! Watch out for deadlocks. I would think it is more important to have the list as such thread-safe. Hint: there are better algorithms (lock-less, non-blocking) to be found by a simple search.

Comment: It's a step before implementing the Optimistic algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will be the same mutex.

You can malloc a new mutex element each time you need new mutex like this :

`malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)))`

an intialize like this :

`pthread_mutex_init(m, NULL)`

Comment: So now should I use the lock like this: (pthread_mutex_lock(node->mutex)) insted of like this: (pthread_mutex_lock(&(node->mutex)) )?

Comment: @GalHyams
malloc return a `(void *)` i.e a pointer so it must be hold by a pointer to a `mutex` i.e. now your mutex member in each node must be of type mutex pointer and then you will `malloc` it a new `mutex` and pass as `(pthread_mutex_lock(node->mutex)) `